# How are made animations that starts just when user sees them

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm wondering. How CSS3 animations are made. I am interested in the easiest way possible. 
This effect is: [here](http://jackietrananh.com/shop.php) or [here](https://layervault.com)

I was looking at the jquery waypoints - but I don't think that it's a solution they are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean when it is triggered or how the animation is done? In your first example the author uses css3 transitions to achive the effect. He basically scales the image down a little bit and then uses a transition to get back to scale 1:

```
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: scale(1);
-moz-transform: scale(1);
-ms-transform: scale(1);
-o-transform: scale(1);
transform: scale(1);
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
```

The effect is triggered after you scroll to a certain point of the page (there are different solutions for that, i.e. waypoints) and then the class "show-item" is added.

You can read more about transitions here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

In your second example the animations are integrated videos, so that is not the same.

Comment: can You please explain me, how it looks like in practice? How to build css to start something on x height (scroll properties) ?

Comment: I would suggest something like this plugin that fires an event when the element becomes visible http://plugins.jquery.com/appear/. If you want to do it by hand, you basically have to calculate the position of the elment vs. how far the user has scrolled like in this example: http://blog.pamelafox.org/2012/02/delayed-image-loading-on-long-pages.html

Comment: Thank You. The jQuery Appear looks like the thing I am looking forward to learn. Many thanks for Your helpful answer! Bye